# Windows 10 Screensaver file names

Tags: windows-10, screensaver

Is there a way to have a screen saver in Windows 10 show the file names on the pictures displayed?

Sure would be nice to know exactly where those files are.

Answer (score 2):

If have an old computer with WinXP, search for file ssmypics.scr. That's the MY Pictures Slideshow screensaver. If you don't have a XP computer handy, you can probably find that file online. Copy that file to your Win 10 computer. Right click on the file, choose "Install" from the drop down.......My Pictures Slideshow should now be available as one of your choices on the Screensaver Settings Panel. You can configure My Pictures Slideshow to show file names. I've done this on Win 7 and Win 10.

Comment: Wow. Thanks mark, I'll try that on my Win 10 PC. (Stackexchange way out of my league). Appreciate this.

Answer (score 0):

In windows 10 they are .scr files, stored in different folders in the

> C:\Windows\WinSxs

folders.

Search the Windows folder for

> .scr

to find them

Comment: except...  OP is referencing pictures, and is probably thinking of a slideshow that shows pictures.  Considering how imprecise the question's text matched the topic/subject's, I question whether OP was even meaning to ask about screensavers, or desktop backgrounds.  The "lock screen" might be even more probable as the intended topic.

Comment: Ah ha, yes, quite right. It's my desktop background that displays photos from a folder in a sub folder in another sub folder.... Photos I haven't seen in decades. It would be nice if the background file name could be displayed in order to locate the photo quickly. Much older version of Windows had a simple check box in the desktop background routine that could be checked to also show the file name. @TOOGAM

Comment: Well, it's obvious to me I'm totally in the wrong place for a novice. I don't know the techno language and I can't write code. I'm not sure I can even describe the problem correctly. This IS an issue I'm having with my screen saver. Put simply, I'd like it to display the file names with the photos. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

Re putting picture titles in a picture slideshow as screen saver in Windows 10 (It also works for XP, Vista, 7, and 8, according to its creator.), there is a really good program that is pretty easy to use:
Here is the URL for it, if it is permitted to give URLS on this site.
https://www.gphotoshow.com

I have found that gPhotoShow allows you to have the title shown for each picture. There is a paid and a free version, and I am not sure which one I have, but once you have installed the software, go to your computer's Settings (or right click on the desktop and choose Personalize.

Then over to the left, choose Lockscreen and go way down to the bottom to Screensaver settings.
Click on that and in the box that comes up, choose gPhotoShow Screen saver from the list and click (over to the right) on Settings.  In Settings, choose the Images tab. I think the little box for Recursive Search needs to be checked.

In that same tab, you need to have the pictures for your slide show in the folder (that you can always find located in your computer's Pictures folder) called "New folder for gPhotoShow."  I think that installing the program automatically creates this folder for you and you probably have to have your selected pictures in there for gPhotoShow to work.  (I have a vague recollection that it didn't work for me until I put the pictures into that particular folder.)

Now you are ready to tweak things so that the titles you have given to the various pictures will show at the bottom of the screen when the slide show is at work. Click on the tab for Images Options.  In the box that this brings up, look down to around the middle of the box for "Image File Informations," under which there is a little box where you can click for "Show File Name," and over to the right you can even decide the color of the font. I am using bright red for that, which seems to show up well against most backgrounds; there is even an option for choosing the size of the font.

I think gPhotoShow is really great--it has many functions, and I have been using it almost from the start after buying a Windows 10 computer maybe a year ago, without ever having any problems with it.  There are several different transitions from picture to picture, if you want that--and I do. Sometimes they surprise me.  The program will even let you put music to the screen saver, but I have not tried that part of it.

I would like to give credit to whatever site first made me aware of gPhotoShow, but unfortunately, I can't remember.